# rails date calculation in factory girl `-': expected numeric (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

This is my code:

```
require 'date'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :construction_site do
    startdate = Date.today - rand(500)
    enddate = startdate + (1 + rand(1000))
    name { Faker::Lorem.words(2) }
    address {Faker::Address.street_address + "\n" + Faker::Address.zip_code + " " + Faker::Address.city} 
    internalnumber { "CON" + ( 1 + rand(50000)) }
    self.begin { startdate }
    self.end { enddate }
    finished { enddate < Date.today }
    user
    customer
  end
end
```

and I get this error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/
date/calculations.rb:100:in `-': expected numeric (TypeError)
        from /Users/kannix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_supp
ort/core_ext/date/calculations.rb:100:in `minus_with_duration'
        from /Users/kannix/railsapp/spec/factories/construction_sites.rb:5
:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/kannix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl
/syntax/default.rb:18:in `instance_eval'
        from /Users/kannix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl
/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
        from /Users/kannix/railsapp/spec/factories/construction_sites.rb:4
:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/kannix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl
/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
        from /Users/kannix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl
/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
        from /Users/kannix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl
/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
        from /Users/kannix/railsapp/spec/factories/construction_sites.rb:3
:in `<top (required)>'
```

Where is my error and are there other things in that code that should be changed? (I'm new to rails ;) )

Comment: I don't know what the problem is.  From the line numbers and the error message, I suspect it's the line "startdate = Date.today - rand(500)".  Try commenting out the rest of the lines inside the do...end, to confirm that, and simplify the question.

Comment: It is definitely the line where I set startdate, check it by commenting out the other stuff.. I posted the whole code to get some feedback for the rest of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
require 'date'

FactoryGirl.define do
  startdate = Date.today + 100
  factory :construction_site do
    name { Faker::Lorem.words(2) }
    address {Faker::Address.street_name + ' ' + rand(1000).to_s + "\n" + Faker::Address.zip_code + ' ' + Faker::Address.city} 
    internal_number { "CON" + ( 1 + rand(50000)).to_s }
    self.begin { startdate - rand(500) }
    self.end { startdate + rand(1000) }
    finished { self.end < Date.today }
    user
    customer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following lines:

```
startdate = Date.today - rand(500)
enddate = startdate + (1 + rand(1000))
```

to:

```
startdate { Date.today - rand(500).days }
enddate { startdate + (1 + rand(1000)).days }
```

Adding `.days` will keep `startdate` and `enddate` as `Date` object

Comment: do I have to require something to use the days method? btw my syntax works in IRB

Comment: undefined method `days' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static
:0x007f9734a195f0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: I just edited the answer. The problem is that you are using attribution (`startdate = ...`). You must pass the value as a parameter to `startdate` or inside a block (when you have dynamic values, like yours). Also, try both with and without the `.days` call and tell us which works

Comment: You can also try rand(500).to_i and rand(500).to_i.days.

Comment: @MarlinPierce  undefined method `to_i' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static:0x007f8cb431a338>

Comment: @LuccaMordente startdate isnt a attribute.. it is a local variable which is assigned in this line self.begin { startdate }

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to assign these values before the factory declaration?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  startdate = Date.today - rand(500)
  enddate = startdate + (1 + rand(1000))

  factory :construction_site do
    name { Faker::Lorem.words(2) }
    address {Faker::Address.street_address + "\n" + Faker::Address.zip_code + " " + Faker::Address.city} 
    internalnumber { "CON" + ( 1 + rand(50000)) }
    self.begin { startdate }
    self.end { enddate }
    finished { enddate < Date.today }
    user
    customer
  end
end
```

Or even before the first line.

Comment: that one works but will lead to a new problem that all my construction side models will get the same start and end date